# Why does list comprehension sort enumerated indices?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I ran into something interesting using list comprehension to find matching strings in two lists:

```
decoded_chans1 =  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'H']
user_chans1 =     ['H', 'B', 'C']
adj_index_list = [index for index, decoded_ch in enumerate(decoded_chans1) 
                  for user_ch in user_chans1 
                  if user_ch == decoded_ch]
#output
In[23]: adj_index_list
Out[23]: [1, 2, 4]
```

What I'm looking for is `adj_index_list` to be filled immediately when a match is made: insert `'H'` index in `decoded_chans1` into `adj_index_list` at same index position of `'H'` in  `user_chans1`. This is accomplished when avoiding list comprehension, and writing out the for loops proper:

```
adj_index_list = []
for user_ch in user_chans1:
    for i, decoded_ch in enumerate(decoded_chans1):
        if user_ch == decoded_ch:
            adj_index_list.append(i)
#output
In[25]: adj_index_list
Out[25]: [4, 1, 2]
```

Can someone tell me whether I'm missing something subtle in the list comprehension I constructed, or if list comprehension inherently runs some sort of behind the scenes sorting?

Thanks!

Comment: You made a mistake in assuming that list comprehensions "flip" the loops. They don't. So your list comp is not the correct conversion of your normal loop. [see docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch around the order of your `for` loops in your comprehension:

```
decoded_chans1 =  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'H']
user_chans1 =     ['H', 'B', 'C']
adj_index_list = [index for user_ch in user_chans1 
                  for index, decoded_ch in enumerate(decoded_chans1) 
                  if user_ch == decoded_ch]
```

In list comprehensions, the `for` loop that appears first is the one that is your "outer" loop.

Comment: Ah of course, thank you! i had the very wrong belief that the "outer" loop was the "outermost" loop written. i believe your answer is also what @Paritosh Singh was trying to say in their comment on the main question. thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is sorted; the elements of `decoded_chans1` are checked in the order they appear.

1. `(0, 'A')`: is `A` in `user_chans`? No, don't include 0 in the result.
2. `(1, 'B')`: is `B` in `user_chans`? Yes, include 1 in the result.
3. `(2, 'C')`: is `C` in `user_chans`? Yes, include 2 in the result.
4. `(3, 'D')`: is `D` in `user_chans`? No, don't include 3 in the result.
5. `(4, 'H')`: is `H` in `user_chans`? Yes, include 4 in the result.

The fact that `for user_ch in user_chans1 if user_ch == decoded_ch` is (assuming uniqueness of elements in `user_chans1`) just a long-winded way of saying `if user_ch in user_chans1` doesn't affect the iteration order of `decoded_chans1`.

*However*, if there are duplicates in `user_chans1`, it would be possible for a given index to appear multiple times in the result, though still in the order in which `decoded_chans1` provides. Given `user_chans1 = ['B', 'H', 'B', 'C']`, then the result would have been `[1, 1, 2, 4]`.

Comment: perhaps your answer can be reduced as what you're saying is related to the solution from @iz_. in my incorrect list comprehension, i'm matching strings in `user_chans` with a string in `decoded_chans1`, instead of matching strings in `decoded_chans1` with a string in `user_chans1`. This is because the `for` loops are not ordered appropriately. While i agree list comp is not sorting the indices as you stated, i'm not sure `for user_ch in user_chans1 if user_ch == decoded_ch` can be replaced with `if user_ch in user_chans1` as you stated.